# Is there a command on Mac can show the disk IO input and output stats?

Tags: macos, command-line

I can use `vmstat` on ubuntu linux to show IO input and output stats. Whether there is a build-in command in MacOS do the same output?

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 266800 1408168 25417796    0    0     3    76   35   46  1  1 98  0  0
 0  0      0 266708 1408168 25417796    0    0     0  1032 1693 4065  1  1 98  0  0
 0  0      0 267156 1408168 25417808    0    0     0     0 1819 4443  2  1 97  0  0
 0  0      0 266872 1408168 25417828    0    0     0    12 1298 3724  1  1 98  0  0
```

I can use `iostat` to check disk IO stats but it doesn't show input and output. It shows a total number of bytes on the disk.

I don't want to install 3rd party library to do that. Is there a command I can use on Mac?

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing to getting IO r/w info is `iotop` command, which comes with all Mac OS (see `disk_r` and `disk_w`).

```
$ sudo iotop
2019 Jul 15 22:39:17,  load: 1.19,  disk_r:      0 KB,  disk_w:    628 KB

  UID    PID   PPID CMD              DEVICE  MAJ MIN D            BYTES
    0      1      0 launchd          ??        1   2 W           643072
    0      0      0                  ??        1   2             649216
```

If you are running on Mac OSX 10.10 (El Capitan) or later, then you need to first disable the SIP (System Integration Protection) for `dtrace` in order to run `iotop` because `iotop` uses `dtrace`.  For older OSX, you can ignore the following steps.

To disable SIP for dtrace (and iotop) for Mac OSX 10.10 and above:

1. Turn on or Restart your Mac
2. As the Mac is turning on, hold down Command-R to boot into Recovery Mode
3. Open terminal and type `csrutil disable` (this is a temporary step)
4. type `csrutil enable --without dtrace`. (It re-enables SIP except for dtrace)
5. Reboot your Mac

Now you can run `iotop` and `dtrace`.

- If you want to restore SIP to its original state, and to prevent dtrace from running, reboot into Recovery Mode and in terminal, type `csrutil enable` and reboot.

Comment: Also for a very verbose version of i/o monitoring, fs_usage is can be informative if you filter the output.  http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/20/monitor-disk-activity-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: This shows bytes, but it does not show latency, I want to see how long CPU is waiting for an IO device to respond. Any solution for this? - IOWait is what it's called on Linux and it shows in a few different tools including in top.

Answer (score -3):

The nettop command might be useful.

For options see

```
man nettop
```

Comment: network ≠ disk IO